# Assigning values to specific subscript indices in 3D python array throws errors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, indices

Say I have initialized an array in 3D as:

```
arr_3d = np.zeros((100, 100, 100))
```

Now I want to change the elements at subscript indices `(i, j, k)` of `arr_3d` to some value (say 1), where `i, j, k` are the list (or array) of indices with sizes `100, 100, 40`, respectively, along the three axes. I have tried `arr_3d[i, j, k] = 1`, but it throws an error. I have tried converting the subscript indices to linear indices by `np.ravel_multi_index()`, but it looks like it can't convert the subscript indices of a 3D array.

The above issue is easy to solve in Matlab, where using `arr_3d(i, j, k) = 1` works.

Comment: The default for MATLAB is to index arrays as blocks, in this case a (100,100,40) block.  The closest numpy equivalent is `arr_3d[np.ix_(i,j,k)]`, where `np.ix_` converts the 3 flat arrays into 3d arrays.  Run that `np.ix_` expression alone (for smaller samples) to see what it does.  More on numpy indexing at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

Comment: The numpy `[i,j,k]` indexing is more like MATLABs linear indexing with `idx = sub2ind(size(A), i,j,k)`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks, Paul. It seems to be working, but the order is not maintained. For instance, `a = np.zeros((4, 4, 4))`, and `a[np.ix_([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [0,1])] = 1` returns an array whose 2nd and 3rd dimension elements sweemed to have been swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with different dimensions,ones that are distinct

```
In [1375]: a=np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
In [1376]: a[np.ix_([0], [1,2], [0,1])] = 1
In [1377]: a
Out[1377]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

`numpy` divides the array in to 'planes' on the first dimension; MATLAB does it on the last.  So this shows 2 planes or blocks, each 3x4.

In octave

```
>> a = zeros(2,3,4);
>> a([1],[2,3],[1,2]) = 1
a =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0   1   1
   0   0   0

ans(:,:,2) =

   0   1   1
   0   0   0

ans(:,:,3) =

   0   0   0
   0   0   0

ans(:,:,4) =

   0   0   0
   0   0   0
```

4 blocks of 2x3.